# PHP input stream returning 0 data - Laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, stream, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get chunked uploads working on a form in my Laravel 4 project. The client side bit works so far, the uploads are chunking in 2MB chunks, and data is being sent from the browser. There's even have a handy progress bar in place to show the upload progress.

The problem is on the PHP side, as I'm unable to write the contents of the upload stream to disk. The system always ends up with a 0 byte file created. The idea is to append the chunks to the already uploaded file as they arrive.

The project is built on Laravel 4, so I'm not sure if Laravel reads the **php://input** stream and does something with it. Since **php://input** can only be read once, it possibly means that by the time when my controller actually tries to read it the stream, it would be empty.

The controller looks as follows:

```
public function upload()
{
    $filename = Config::get('tms.upload_path') . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    file_put_contents($filename, fopen('php://input', 'r'), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The file is being created, but it's length always remains at 0 bytes. Any ideas how I can coax the contents of the **php://input** stream out of the system?

Answer (score 1):

afaik fopen returns a pointer to file, and not an stream, so probably it is not good as a parameter for file_put_contents

can you try with this workaround, instead of your file_put_contents?

```
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

$fp = fopen($filename, "a");

while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
```

Comment: No matter what I try, $putdata in your example, would always contain ''

Comment: but in my example, putdata is a pointer to a file, not an string. thats why i use the while loop. if you want to have the contents of the input, use `$string= file_get_contents("php://input");` or if you do it like in my example, and you want to check the content besides of writing it to the file, use `while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)){ $string.=$data;
  fwrite($fp, $data); }`

Comment: Thanks Carlos. $content = file_get_contents("php://input"); is what I tried, but it returns "". I even tried what this link suggests: http://www.codingswag.com/2013/07/get-raw-post-data-in-laravel/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could the problem be this: Content-Type multipart/form-data; I see this is in the request header, and according to the PHP docs, php://input isn't available with multipart/form-data. So I need to look at why jQuery file uploader does the request with multipart form data, and try to turn it off.

Comment: There are two options to this, I can turn off multipart on the jQuery file uploader, losing the ability to send additional form data, or I can use a different method to read the contents. Not sure how thought...

Comment: for sure it wont work with multipart/form-data. but, your are using multipart/form-data and sending the contents in the body of the post request?

Comment: if the contents are in the raw body of the post, you could use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA but it is also not available with multipart/form-data. so probably the best is to turn it off in the uploader

Comment: also, if you want to use  multipart/form-data, you can asign the data chunks to a variable, so you can retrieve them in the normal $_POST array

Comment: Turning multipart off seems to fix it. Thanks for the guidance. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple, I needed to turn off multipart/form-data and use `file_get_contents("php://input")` to read the contents and pass the result to `file_put_contents()` like so:

```
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents("php://input"), FILE_APPEND);
```

This works and fixes my problems.